# Infopath 2010 validate "I agree" checkbox before submitting

Tags: infopath

In Infopath 2010 how do I add the validation for a "I agree" checkbox before submitting the webform into sharepoint?

Any tips will be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a checkbox on your InfoPath form and set it to **required**. This way the user needs to check it before he / she is able to submit the form. If required doesn't cut it, just add a validation to the checkbox, so it needs to be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

For set validations for multiple checkboxes in INFOPATH:
Here a nice solution~
Sset the checkbox column as single line of text and make it mandatory in Sahrepoint list. Now in Infopath drag that coulmn and change control to checkbox..do the same of other checkboxes and it works :) hope it helps someone